# Flask Loading Screen while generating a PDF

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to figure out a way where I can provide users with a loading screen.
When users clicks a button (not submit), it will talk to the server and generates a PDF on-fly. This process takes about 3.2 seconds and I want to provide loading screen during that time. The problem that I am facing is that, a lot of available solutions for loading screen requires a page to reload ('post' in this case) to turn off the loading gif and this is giving me a trouble.
Below is my downloading PDF view function.
I am looking for a solution where a loading screen will be provided upon clicking PDF download button and the loading screen will go away right before a PDF file is downloaded.

```
@post_user_blueprint.route('/download_pdf/<string:test_id>/<string:created_on>/<string:test_type>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@human_readable_log('Downloaded a PDF')
def download(test_id, created_on, test_type):
    from app.views.utility import PDFSystem

    pdf_system = PDFSystem(test_id=test_id, created_on=created_on, test_type=test_type)
    pdf = pdf_system.create_pdf('dynamic_pdf_template.html')
    _filename = test_type +'_'+ test_id
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + _filename

    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of routing user on a different URL after button is clicked, use JavaScript AJAX to call the download route and display some loader until your AJAX doesn't return something useful, whatever you return to it from your `download` route.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is a server side framework. It can just communicate to your client using requests. What you need is a way to communicate to the server in a asynchronous way (using AJAX). You will send a request to the server asking for the PDF and while it waits for the response it will show the loading page or symbol. You can do this using JQuery (or something like that) on your client side code